# How to get an app_id for Facebook comments box plugin in order to moderate the comments

Tags: facebook, comments, identification

I want to be able to moderate Facebook comments that I have integrated. They say to use the following tag.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

But from where do I get the `app_id` and where do I paste this tag in my code?

Answer (score 4):

Set yourself up with an application using the [Facebook Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

If this is your first Facebook application you will have to validate your account as a developer.
Once you have the App ID, include it in the initialisation of your comments plugin, and you can use that interface to manage the comments.